# Xelatex not recognizing fonts installed

Tags: fonts, microtype, undefined

I'm using Linux Mint, and I'm collaborating in a project of a book. There are many custom packages created, and one of them in respect of the fonts.

The fonts defined are:

```
\RequirePackage{ifthen}

\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Exo2-Light.otf}
\newfontfamily{\titlefont}{orbitron-medium.otf}
\newfontfamily{\secondtitlefont}{orbitron-black.ttf}
\newfontfamily{\thirdtitlefont}{orbitron-bold.otf}
\newfontfamily{\pagetitlefont}{Orbitron-Regular.ttf}
\newfontfamily{\boxfont}{Roboto}
\newfontfamily{\enumeratefont}{Exo2-Light.otf}
\newfontfamily{\boxtitlefont}{Exo2-Bold.otf} 
\newfontfamily{\extitlefont}{Exo2-SemiBold.otf}   
\newfontfamily{\boxexample}{Exo2-Regular.otf}
```

There are many environments defined with these fonts, but for some reason, even though all of the fonts are installed in my computer,some of them are causing errors when I try to compile, such as:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/Exo2-Light.otf(0)/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `T1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 105.
```

and a lot of errors of this kind:

```
Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `\k A'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in inheritance list
(microtype)                `microtype.cfg/375(protrusion)'.
```

Some of them are really strange, like this, where it substitutes for apparently the same font:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/orbitron-medium.otf(0)/bx/n' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/orbitron-medium.otf(0)/m/n' instead on input line 11.
```

If someone could help me I'd be grateful.

Comment: `LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape \`T1/Exo2-Light.otf(0)/m/n' undefined` indicates you have incorrect setup in the document, you should be using Unicode (TU) encoding with OTF not the 8-bit T1 encoding which is just for (pdf)latex. If you have `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` delete that line.

Comment: Should I use any package for the TU encoding? Because I deleted the line and I still have the same problem.

Comment: No TU is the default (and only encoding that you can use with fontspec or xelatex) if you still get warnings about T1/... then almost certainly you are loading fontenc somewhere (the log file would show the details)

Comment: the last warning is not strange, it just says that there is no bold font for that family and it is substituting medium weight.